# É correto declarar métodos GET/SET dentro de uma classe STRATEGY?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Fiquei com uma dúvida quando fui criar um padrão de projeto do tipo **Strategy**. É correto declarar métodos `GET` e `SET` em uma classe que implementa uma interface **Strategy**? Não sei se fui bem claro, segue o exemplo:

`Strategy`:

```
public interface Strategy {
    String getNome();
}
```

Classe `Imovel`:

```
public abstract Imovel {
    protected String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Classe utilizando padroes **Factory** e **Strategy**:

```
public class Apartamento extends Imovel implements Strategy {

    public Apartamento() {
        tipo = "apartamento";
        status = "disponivel";
    }

    @Override
    public float getNome() {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

**Não** é necessário declarar getters e setters para nenhum objeto, a menos que você pretenda usá-los.

Dito isto, há várias coisas que você precisa entender sobre o Java, Orientação a Objetos e os padrões citados na pergunta para então conseguir compreender a resposta para a pergunta.

## Problemas

### Padrões Strategy e Factory

O exemplo da pergunta não implementa o padrão Strategy. Esse padrão consiste em que a superclasse implemente um algoritmo e um ou mais passos desse algoritmo são implementados pelas subclasses. Apenas usar uma interface não é o mesmo que implementar o padrão de projeto.

Um exemplo de Strategy:

```
abstract class PizzaMaker {
    public Pizza fazerPizza() {
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
        adicionarCobertura(pizza);
        Forno.assar(pizza);
        return pizza;
    }
    abstract void adicionarCobertura(Pizza pizza);
}
```

Então você pode implementar as diferentes estratégias de como cobrir uma pizza.

Exemplo

```
class MussarelaPizzaMaker extends PizzaMaker {
    void adicionarCobertura(Pizza pizza) {
        pizza.add("Molho");
        pizza.add("Mussarela");
        pizza.add("Orégano");
    }
}
```

E quanto ao padrão Factory, o exemplo da pergunta também  não o implementa, pois não há nenhum método que retorna um objeto.

No exemplo que eu coloquei acima, o método `fazerPizza` é um *factory method* e também pode-se considerar que essa classe implementa o padrão Factory porque cada subclasse vai retornar um tipo diferente de pizza.

Portanto, esse exemplo mostra como usar os padrões Strategy e Factory em conjunto.

### Outros problemas

No seu exemplo há alguns erros e problemas.

Por exemplo, o método `getNome` em `Apartamento` tenta sobrescrever o `getNome` de `Imovel`, porém o tipo de retorno muda. Isso não é possível em Java.

Além disso, não faz muito sentido sobrescrever o método nesse caso sendo que ele já vai ser herdado pela classe `Apartamento`. A não ser, é claro, que houvesse algo diferente no novo método, o que não parece ser o caso.

Um problema conceitual com o exemplo é que não me parece muito razoável aplicar os padrões Strategy e Factory em classes que aparentam ser classes de domínio, gerando assim uma hierarquia de tipos.

Seria melhor ter os seus tipos básicos sendo POJOs, com getters e setters necessários, depois implementar outras classes para atuar como fábricas e ainda outras classes para implementar algoritmos possivelmente usando diferentes estratégicas. Claro que existe exceção para tudo, mas em geral é assim que se faz para evitar classes com múltiplas responsabilidades.

Enfim, classes de domínio como `Imovel` não necessariamente precisa de subtipos para cada tipo de imóvel. Isso pode ficar bonito no diagrama para mostrar ao professor ou cliente, mas na prática é um pesadelo de manutenção.

Ter um atributo `tipo` e alguns atributos opcionais geralmente é mais que suficiente para lidar com pequenas variações a não ser que no contexto do seu sistema cada tipo de imóvel seja um cidadão de primeira classe, isto é, possa ter regras de negócio distintas e um ciclo de via próprio.